# Sequelize - Subselect association to filter parent model

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.5

I've recently started to use `Sequelize 6`. Currently trying to express the following query unsuccessfully.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
JOIN requests r
ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE (r.status = true AND r.created_at IN (SELECT 
 MAX(r.created_at)
 FROM users u
 INNER JOIN requests r ON r.user_id = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id))
GROUP BY u.id, r.id
```

What I have tried so far:

```
const result = await User.findAll({
  offset: page,
  subQuery: false,
  limit: rowsPerPage,
  where: {
    '$requests.status$': true,
  },
  include: [{
    as: 'requests',
    model: Request,
    separate: true,
    required: true,
    order: [['createdAt', 'desc']],
    limit: 1,  // problem is here -> error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "requests"
  }],
});
```

In other words, I'm trying to load the parent model **only** when the association's `status` value is true on the **last record**, and return each individual user row alongside with its latest association.

Regarding the limit problem on my comment, this thread might be useful

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11617

Comment: Looks like your original query is not quite matching what you are trying to do in Sequelize. Could you double check your original query? Try it on your DB and see if you are getting what you expect.  To me, the query looks like it only returns 1 record of only user data.  (inner join with single created_at timestamp + select is only u.*)

Comment: @Emma you are absolutely right. I was working on it today and i encountered what you described. I have updated my query :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to change original SQL a little bit to work with Sequelize because a certain combination of `required`, `where` didn't work well.

So, I went off from your description.

> I'm trying to load the parent model only when the association's status
> value is true on the last record

If I understand this correctly, I think you can use `having` query to achieve this.

```
const result = await User.findAll({
    offset: page,
    subQuery: false,
    limit: rowsPerPage,
    include: [{
        as: 'requests',
        model: Request,
        required: true
    }],
    having: { 
        '$requests.createdAt$': [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('`requests`.`createdAt`'))],
        '$requests.status$': true
    },
    group: ['users.id'],
});
```

This will produce a following SQL.  Please try this SQL and let me know if this is what you are looking for or not.

```
SELECT ... FROM `users` AS `users` 
INNER JOIN `requests` AS `requests` 
ON `users`.`id` = `requests`.`userId` 
GROUP BY `users`.`id` 
HAVING `requests`.`createdAt` IN (MAX(`requests`.`createdAt`)) AND `requests`.`status` = 1 
LIMIT 0, 5;
```